# Уведомления в Android API 26

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не правильно? До API 26 у меня уведомления работали идеально, но с API 26 появились каналы и чтобы красными не подчеркивалось и работало нормально Android Студия просит чтобы я прописал минимальный уровень API 26, а мне надо 17, но чтобы и на Android 8 уведомление об ошибке не высвечивалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте очистить кэш проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там где создаете канал нужно

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
```

Comment: красное подчеркивание всё равно не исчезает

Comment: Не может быть. А что теперь пишет на красном подчеркивание ?

Comment: тоже самое - я обновил картинку

Comment: Какой-то глюк андроид студии. Могу посоветовать только попробовать сделать clean Project, Rebuild и перезапустить андроид студию. Ошибки не должно быть в исправленном варианте.

Comment: а ты можешь ответить на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815642/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-android-api-26