# Уведомление в Android API 26

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, создал уведомление с учетом API 26, но на эмуляторе Android 8 при вызове уведомления выскакивает окошко со звуком(стрелкой отмечено часть окна приложения), а мне нужно только, чтобы отображался только значок "G". На эмуляторах более ранних версиях API отображается нормально, без звукового уведомления. Что ещё нужно дописать в каналах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю что вашу проблему решит вызов:

```
channel.setSound(null,null);
```

Но учтите что вам создавать канал лучше не в сервисе, а на запуск приложения. И если до этого канал был уже создан, то ваш вызов создания канал не будет работать. По этому после изменения кода создания канала нужно удалять приложение и устанавливать заново. 
Подробней написано тут https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html#CreateChannel

Comment: звук все равно есть, а мне желательно вообще чтобы окно уведомления не появлялось, только значок в панели

Comment: А вы уверены что вам нужно IMPORTANCE_HIGH? Может все же сменить на IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT?

Comment: тоже не помогает, я прежде чем задать вопрос пробовал даже с IMPORTANCE_LOW - всё равно окно опускается со звуком

Comment: Сейчас проверил не зависимо от IMPORTANCE_* с помощью channel.setSound(null,null); звук отключается. Чтобы окно не появлялось поверх других не используйте IMPORTANCE_HIGH. Лучше всего IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT.

Comment: И не забывайте про то что вам нужно полностью удалить приложение чтобы новые параметры канала вступили в силу (я давал ссылку на документацию). Если просто перезапустить приложение из android studio в эмуляторе канал не будет пересоздан с новыми параметрами

Comment: ну теперь заработало